# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'siteId' was called on null

Tags: flutter

hi I work to update mobile application build with flutter .but when I run this app I get this error. **Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'siteId' was called on null.**

```
  _getTitles() {
    try {
        int aux = audites.length;
        for (Audite a in audites) {
          String title;
          _personnelAuditController
              .getPersonnelAuditListById(a.idPersonnelAudit)
              .then((_) {
                print("start");
            _siteController.getSite(_.siteId).then((__) {//the error line
              title = "${_.nom}  (${__.nom})";


              if (_titles.length == aux - 1) {
                setState(() {
                  _titles.add(title);
                });
              } else {
                _titles.add(title);
              }
            });
          });
        }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      _showAlertDialog('Opération non supportée', "Erreur : " + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: `_` discards the passed variables if I recall correctly, try a different variable name instead of `_`

Comment: thank you.   could you explain more

Comment: @LW001 is saying change your variable name from `_` to `site` or whatever you want to call it. For Example => `.getPersonnelAuditListById(a.idPersonnelAudit).then((site) { ... })` and then when you want `siteId` you do this => `_siteController.getSite(site.siteId)`. You should probably also change the double-underscore that you use with the `_siteController` future call also.